# Install the latest version of a package that is compatible with the installed version of node

Tags: node.js, npm

I have node 0.8.22 installed on my dev and production machines. I want to install a package for example gulp or grunt that is compatible with 0.8.22.

If I run the following npm attempts to install the latest gulp package and reports warnings because it requires node > 0.9.

```
npm install gulp -g
```

I know that I can run

> npm view gulp versions

to get the version list and then use "npm install -g gulp@3.3.2" to get a particular version.

Is there away to do something like the following so I don't have to manually try each version until I get the compatible package?

```
npm install gulp@Latest_compatible -g
```

Comment: I have the same question posted in another way basically asking why a package manager is unable to resolve compatible packages. It's kind of core requirement imo coming from composer and php where only a version compatible with ALL dependacies is installed for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [npm-compat](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-compat). Is easy to use, or you can implement your own way.